# Is 'second' a keyword in mysql full-text searches?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a simple MySQL table that is setup for full text search.

```
| id | title         |
----------------------
| 1  | test event    |
| 2  | Second test   |
| 3  | Larry's event |
| 4  | this second   |
```

When I use the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EVENTS
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('test event' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I get back 3 rows; the ones containing 'test event', 'Second test', and 'Larry's Event'.

Now If I run the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EVENTS
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('second' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Nothing is returned... strange?

Lastly, if I run the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EVENTS
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('second test' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I get back 2 rows; the ones containing 'test event' and 'Second test'.

I appears that the word 'second' cannot be searched or needs to be escaped somehow.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [second](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) is a stop word & will be ingored. (You can [override](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) this behaviour)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it's a stopword:

[Fulltext stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)

if you have access to the mySQL server, you can change the stopword list file as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html). If it's a shared server, you may be out of luck.